# How to ask prolog if there's only one logical answer

Tags: prolog

I am trying to come up with a query in Prolog, where I ask if there is a value where *x^2=25*. But, I only want it to return *`yes`* if, in the knowledge base, there is only one case where *x^2* is *25*.

I have this in my knowledge base:

```
squared(5,25) 
squared((-5),25)
```

I want the program to return *`no`* because there are two answers of `x` where *x^2=25*, when I only want one.

So far I have this:

```
squared(x,25),squared(x,25), x=x.
```

Comment: The thing that you have at the bottom, what does it do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `forall/2` as follows:

```
squared(X, 25), forall(squared(Y, 25), X = Y).
```

This query succeeds only when all solutions to `squared(X, 25)` have the same value.

To elaborate a bit:

```
squared(X, 25),                 % we have a single solution, X
forall(squared(Y, 25), X = Y).  % we are asserting all solutions are equal to X
```

If you are unfamiliar with `forall/2`:

> `forall(Condition, Action)` succeeds if for all alternative bindings of Condition, Action can be proven. It is equivalent to `\+ (Condition, \+ Action)`.

So this works for predicates which have roots with multiplicity `> 1` (it might not be what you desire, in which case `findall` might help). The following will ensure that you have exactly one root:

```
findall(X, squared(X, 25), [_]).
```

Let us look at an example `X^2 = 0` which has double root at 0:

```
squared(0, 0).
squared(0, 0).
```

So you will have:

```
|?- findall(X, squared(X, 0), [_]).               % check for exactly one root
no

|?- squared(X, 0), forall(squared(Y, 0), X = Y).  % same root with any multiplicity
X = 0 ? 
yes
```

Also variables in prolog start with Captial letters (or _).

EDIT: a more optimal search

```
squared(X, 25), !, forall(squared(Y, 25), X = Y).
```

The cut after `squared(X, 25)` ensures that we iterate through all roots only once. If the `forall` iteration fails, then there exists a `Y` with `squared(Y, 25)` and `Y \= X`. So we do not need to check for different any different `X`.

Comment: @DavidTonhofer : Yeah, a cut is needed. Else if we have `n` non-equal roots, instead of `O(n)` we will have `O(n^2)`.

Comment: Thank you so much, this helped a lot!! BTW do you know another way I could solve this without changing the knowledge base.

Comment: How is the knowledge base changed? It is still `squared(5, 25). squared(-5, 25).` . I only provided the query `squared(X, 25), forall(squared(Y, 25), X = Y).`